# Selenium 4 proxy

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

Есть код на selenium 4.11.2? который должен через прокси открывать сайт 2ip

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def init():
    options = Options()
    options.binary_location = os.getenv("BROWSER_PATH")
    options.proxy = {"httpProxy": f"http://{os.getenv('PROXY_IP')}:{os.getenv('PROXY_PORT')}"}
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    browser.get("https://2ip.ru/")

    browser.quit()


def main():
    init()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Сайт открывается, но айпи показывается мой (прокси проверял, он рабочий). Инфу, о том, как писать прокси взял из документации https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/#proxy. Надо чтобы айпи менялся

Comment: А вы думаетете, что использование прокси гарантированно скрывает реальный ip?

Comment: @СергейШ, задача в том, чтобы зайти на сайт, недоступный из РФ